# Не работает акселерометр на HTC

Tags: android, java

Проблема вот какая, запустил приложение свое на 7 телефонах, везде акселерометр работал и все было нормально, запустил на HTC Desire S нифига не хочет работать, но при этом игра титтер в котором шарик нужно катать работает, что за болт? Как такое может быть, подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На титтер не стоит ориентироваться, быть может там используется гироскоп. Выведи список всех датчиков(список объектов Sensor) на девайсе и будешь уверен в чем проблема. Также попробуй поиграться с инициализацией, параметрами акселерометра, ибо у разных датчиков может быть разная чувствительность и прочие преблуды. Может сам алгоритм работы с акселерометром пропускает значения с НТС.